# How to fetch the data of a specific user in two tables in sql using php

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

The fetching of Data from two tables are already working, but I don't know how to fetch the user's specific data from two tables. I don't know where to place this code //WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
<?php
$seller_id = $_SESSION['seller_id'];
$user_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT seller.s_fname, seller.s_lname, seller.trade_name, seller.s_address, selling_details.opening_time, selling_details.opening_days, selling_details.order_cutoff, selling_details.seller_delivery_time, selling_details.area_covered_delivery, selling_details.delivery_fee FROM seller INNER JOIN selling_details ON seller.seller_id=selling_details.seller_id
WHERE seller.seller_id=selling_details.seller_id");
$seller = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_query);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to embed some parameters to into query we are going to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) attack.

```
// Get seller ID
$seller_id = $_SESSION['seller_id'];

// Prepare the query that will be executed
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT seller.s_fname AS s_fname, seller.s_lname AS s_lname, seller.trade_name AS trade_name, seller.s_address AS s_address, selling_details.opening_time AS opening_time, selling_details.opening_days AS opening_days, selling_details.order_cutoff AS order_cutoff, selling_details.seller_delivery_time AS seller_delivery_time, selling_details.area_covered_delivery AS area_covered_delivery, selling_details.delivery_fee AS delivery_fee FROM seller INNER JOIN selling_details ON seller.seller_id=selling_details.seller_id WHERE seller.seller_id = ?");

// Instead of that '?', put the $seller_id
$stmt->bind_param('i', $seller_id);

// Execute the statement.
$stmt->execute();

// Get the results.
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 

// For each row, get it's associative array representation.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Echo first and last name.
    echo $row['s_fname'].' '.$row['s_lname'].'<br/>';
}

// Close the statement.
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$seller_id = $_SESSION['seller_id'];
$user_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT seller.s_fname, seller.s_lname, seller.trade_name, seller.s_address, selling_details.opening_time, selling_details.opening_days, selling_details.order_cutoff, selling_details.seller_delivery_time, selling_details.area_covered_delivery, selling_details.delivery_fee FROM seller INNER JOIN selling_details ON seller.seller_id=selling_details.seller_id
WHERE seller.id=$seller_id");
$seller = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_query);
?>
```